# ASP.NET webservice

Tags: asp.net

I have written a webservice class with 1 web method("InsertPerson") which takes an argument of another public class(Person, for ex) object( That Person class defined as public in that service class page itself).

Code:

```
Class Service1 : Webservices
{

 [WebMethod]

    public bool InsertPerson(Person p)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Person 
{

    public Person()
    {
    }
    public string PersonName;
    public int Age;
}
```

Now in my client, before i invoke that webmethod "InsertPerson", i just wanted to create object for person class but i cannot find that..

That Person class from service not exposed, Could you please help on this.

Comment: You have asked 12 questions, yet rejected to accept one. You'll get a better response if you first accept some older questions.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried using `[Serialize]` attribute to your Person class?